# Python Webscraper Breaking, Not sure Why

Tags: python, json

I am trying to access a 3rd party ticketing site via API through a web scraper.

I know this is vague but I am new to python and I am not exactly sure how to figure out my error below:

My code breaks on this line:

```
roken_response =r.json
```

I get this error

[image]

Can anyone tell why exactly my code is breaking?

Comment: can be helpful to see more of your code.
You can I believe post pictures directly on SO, the question is supposed to be sufficient without any external links.
Have you tried googling your error? i.e. `Expecting value: line 1 etc.`
it is some JSON parsing error (wrong json format maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `requests` library (which you seem to be using), `.json` is a convenience method that decodes the response as JSON. If your response was not JSON, then you will get a `JSONDecodeError`, as you show in your screenshot.

So the webserver probably answered your request with some HTML or something instead of JSON.

Also it sounds like you are violating the ToS of that poor ticketing site :(